# Uncheck all options on screen one, after checking on screen 2

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a review screen. If I check some of following options on clicking star 4, then it should be uncheck all other options if I already selected on star 1, star 2 etc. [image]

Comment: please post your efforts in the question.

Comment: this could be acheived by jquery. you just support your question with code snippet so that we could help